# Match pattern \\\" using grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, quoting, escape-characters

I have a json string inside json. This got encoded multiple times and I ended up with many escape backlashes: `\\\"`.

The much shortened string looks like,

```
'[{"testId" : "12345", "message": "\\\"the status is pass\\\" comment \\\\\"this is some weird encoding\\\\\""}]'
```

I am trying to grep and get the number of occurrences of the pattern `\\\"` and not `\\\\\"`?

How can I do it?

Any shell/python solution is good to go. In python, using the search string

`search_string = r"""\\\\\"""`, 
throws `unexpected EOF` error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### To look for `\\\"` anywhere on a line:

```
grep -F '\\\"'
```

That is, use `-F` for a fixed string search as opposed to a regular expression match (where backslash is special). And use strong quotes (`'...'`) inside which backslash is not special.

Without `-F`, you'd need to double the backslashes:

```
grep '\\\\\\"'
```

Or use:

```
grep '\\\{3\}"'
grep -E '\\{3}"'
grep -E '[\]{3}"'
```

Within double quotes, you'd need another level of backslashes and also escape the `"` with backslash:

```
#              1
#     1234567890123
grep "\\\\\\\\\\\\\""
```

backslash is another shell quoting operator. So you can also *quote* those backslash and `"` characters with backslash:

```
\g\r\e\p \\\\\\\\\\\\\"
```

I've even quoted the characters of `grep` above though that's not necessary (as none of `g`, `r`, `e`, `p` are special to the shell (except in the Bourne shell if they appear in `$IFS`). The only character I've not quoted is the space character, as we do need its special meaning in the shell: separate arguments.

### To look for `\\\"` provided it's not preceded by another backslash

```
grep -e '^\\\\\\"' -e '[^\]\\\\\\"'
```

That is, look for `\\\"` at the beginning of the line, or following a character other than backslash.

That time, we have to use a regular expression, a fixed-string search won't do.

`grep` returns the lines that match any of those expressions. You can also write it with one expression per line:

```
grep '^\\\\\\"
[^\]\\\\\\"'
```

Or with only one expression:

```
grep '^\(.*[^\]\)\{0,1\}\\\{3\}"' # BRE
grep -E '^(.*[^\])?\\{3}"'        # ERE equivalent
grep -E '(^|[^\])\\{3}"'
```

With GNU `grep` built with PCRE support, you can use a look-behind negative assertion:

```
grep -P '(?<!\\)\\{3}"'
```

### Get a match count

To get a count of the *lines* that match the pattern (that is, that have one or more occurrences of `\\\"`), you'd add the `-c` option to `grep`. If however you want the number of occurrences, you can use the GNU specific `-o` option (though now also supported by a few other implementations) to print all the matches one per line, and then pipe to `wc -l` to get a line-count:

```
grep -Po '(?<!\\)\\{3}"' | wc -l
```

Or standardly/POSIXly, use `awk` instead:

```
awk '{n+=gsub(/(^|[^\\])\\{3}"/,"")};END{print 0+n}'
```

(`awk`'s `gsub()` substitutes and returns the number of substitutions).

Comment: Stephane, thanks for the answer man.. is `grep -e '[^\]\\\\\\"' -e '^\\\\\\"'` different from `grep -e '[^\]\\\\\\"' `? Why do we need the second pattern argument?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar, `grep '[^\]\\\\\\"'` would not match on a line that starts with `\\\"`. As that line would not have that non-backslash character (`[^\]`) before `\\\"`. The second expression looks for `\\\"` at the beginning of the line (`^`).

Comment: yup... it solves it... it is an `or` pattern....